# How to initialise a templated sub-class of vector

Tags: c++

The following example to initialise a vector of vector works fine:

```
using DataElement = std::vector<double>;
using DataVector = std::vector<DataElement>;

DataVector data;
data.emplace_back(DataElement{ 1.0f, 1.0f });
data.emplace_back(DataElement{ 1.1f, 1.1f });
```

Now I would like to make the type of `DataElement` generic, so I tried the following template approach:

```
template <typename T>
class DataElement : public std::vector<T> {};

template <typename T>
class DataVector : public std::vector<DataElement<T>>{};

DataVector<double> data;
data.emplace_back(DataElement<double>{ 1.0f, 1.0f });
data.emplace_back(DataElement<double>{ 1.1f, 1.1f });
```

but this generates an initialisation error on the `emplace_back` lines: `no suitable constructor exists to convert from "float" to "std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>`

I sub-classed vector as that seemed like the right way to then wrap it in a template, but I don't need to sub-class for any other reason, i.e. I don't need to extend the vector class functionality.

Is there an issue with the way I have constructed the generic vector of vectors?

If that is fine, how do I concisely statically initialise an instance of this data structure as per my opening example?

Comment: You probably have to pass in an allocator to the vector. Add an allocator template parameter and set it to std::allocator<T> by default. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: I cannot get your example that works fine to compile. `DataVector` is not a template, so `DataVector<double>` is not valid. It's the equivalent to `std::vector<std::vector<double>><double>`. Equally, `DataElement<double>{ 1.0f, 1.0f }` is really `std::vector<double><double>{ 1.0f, 1.0f })` which is not valid either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `using` with templates.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using DataElement = std::vector<T>;

template <typename T>
using DataVector = std::vector<DataElement<T>>;

int main()
{
    DataVector<double> data;
    data.emplace_back(DataElement<double>{ 1.0f, 1.0f });
    data.emplace_back(DataElement<double>{ 1.1f, 1.1f });
}
```